# Why do data and values I am adding to a table not render until the component is reloaded, even though I can see the new row added?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a React.js app that manages a user's budget on a monthly basis. The app uses a table to populate two pieces of data, 'category' (e.g. "Groceries") and 'budget' (e.g. $500). The table is displayed as such:

```
<table className="budgettable">
        {editMode &&
  <div className="dontdisplay"><div className="newcategoryform">
      <form onSubmit={handleAddCategory}>
 <div className="categoryformcontainer">
  <input className="categorynameinput" type="text" name="categoryName" id="categoryName" placeholder='add new category' required />


  <input className="categoryamountinput" step="1" type="number"  name="budgetAmount" placeholder="$000" id="budgetAmount" required />

  <div className="formbuttoncontainer"><button className="addcategorybutton" type="submit">Add</button></div></div>
</form></div>
</div>
}
          <thead>
            <tr style={{ borderBottom: '0.5px solid #a0a0a0'}}>
              <th style={{ width: '40%', fontSize: '0.8rem', borderBottom: '1px solid #a0a0a0'}}>Category</th>
              {!editMode && <th style={{ width: '20%', fontSize: '0.8rem' }}>Budget</th>}
              {editMode && <th style={{ width: '20%', fontSize: '0.8rem'  }}>Budget</th>}
              {!editMode && <th style={{ width: '15%', fontSize: '0.8rem' }}>Spent</th>}
              {!editMode && <th style={{ width: '20%', fontSize: '0.8rem'  }}>Remaining</th>}
              {editMode && <th style={{ width: '40%', fontSize: '0.8rem', float: 'right'  }}>Action</th>}
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          {sortedBudgets.map(({category, budget}) => {
            
            const isLastUpdatedRow = category === lastUpdatedRowId;
            const remainingBudget = remainingBudgets[category];
            const rowClass = isLastUpdatedRow ? 'highlight' : '';
            const originalBudget = categories[category];
            const isLowBudget = budget / originalBudget > 0 && budget / originalBudget <= 0.2;
            const isNegativeBudget = budget < 0.001;
            const remainingBudgetClass = isLowBudget ? 'remainingbudgettext lowbudget' : isNegativeBudget ? 'remainingbudgettext negativebudget' : 'remainingbudgettext';
            return (
              <tr key={category} className={rowClass}>
                <td className="tableheader">{category}</td>
                <td className="tablenumber">${originalBudget}</td>
                {!editMode && <td className="tablenumber">${(originalBudget - budget).toFixed(2)}</td>}
                {!editMode && <td className={remainingBudgetClass}>${budget.toFixed(2)}</td>}
                
                {editMode && <td><div className="dontdisplay"><button className="deletecategorybutton" onClick={() => handleDeleteCategory(category)}>delete</button></div></td>
}
    
              </tr>
            );
          })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

Notice that when 'editmode' is active on my app, a 'newcategoryform' form appears in/above the table, allowing the user to add a new category name and budget amount. On submit, the 'handleAddCategory' function is invoked. There is also a 'handleDeleteCategory' button, but that is working correctly.

This is the 'handleAddCategory' function:

```
async function handleAddCategory(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const form = event.target;
  const { categoryName, budgetAmount } = form.elements;

  

  
  // Save the new category to Firebase Realtime Database
  categoriesRef.update({
    [categoryName.value]: Number(budgetAmount.value)
  });

  // Update the categories, sortedBudgets, and remainingBudgets states
  setCategories(prevState => {
    const newState = { ...prevState, [categoryName.value]: Number(budgetAmount.value) };
    const sortedBudgets = Object.keys(newState).map(category => ({
      category,
      budget: newState[category],
    })).sort((a, b) => a.category.localeCompare(b.category));

    setSortedBudgets(sortedBudgets);

    const remainingBudgetsCopy = { ...remainingBudgets, [categoryName.value]: Number(budgetAmount.value) };
    setRemainingBudgets(prevState => ({ ...prevState, [categoryName.value]: Number(budgetAmount.value) }));

    return newState;
  });

  setRemainingBudgets(prevState => ({ ...prevState, [categoryName.value]: Number(budgetAmount.value) }));

  // Clear the form inputs
  form.reset();
}
```

When I click the 'Add' button, I can see that the data is being correctly added to the database. In the component, I also see a new table row appear. However, the new row that appears is blank until I re-load the component. If I navigate to a different page in the app, then go back, the data is populated exactly as it should be.

When building this app, the category data was hard-coded, but this button worked correctly. After refactoring it to read and write this info to the database, I noticed the problem.

Why isn't the table in my component showing any data until it is re-loaded?

Here is a related `useEffect` hook that should be listening for changes and writing updates, if this is useful.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // read the budget data from Firebase Realtime Database
  budgetRef.on('child_changed', (snapshot) => {
    const data = snapshot.val() || {};
    const monthlyBudget = Object.values(data).reduce((acc, val) => acc + val, 0);
    setTotalBudget(monthlyBudget);
  });

  // listen for changes in purchases data
  purchasesRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
    const data = snapshot.val() || {};
    const purchasesArray = Object.keys(data).map((key) => ({
      ...data[key],
      id: key,
    }));
    const monthlySpent = purchasesArray.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val.amount, 0);
    setTotalSpent(monthlySpent);

    // calculate the total amount of purchases for each category
    const categoryTotals = purchasesArray.reduce((totals, purchase) => {
      const { category, amount } = purchase;
      return {
        ...totals,
        [category]: (totals[category] || 0) + amount,
      };
    }, {});

    // calculate the remaining budget
    const remainingBudgetsCopy = { ...categories };
    for (const [category, amount] of Object.entries(categoryTotals)) {
      remainingBudgetsCopy[category] = categories[category] - amount;
    }
   
    setRemainingBudgets(remainingBudgetsCopy);

    budgetRef.on('child_changed', (snapshot) => {
      const updatedRowId = snapshot.key;
      setLastUpdatedRowId(updatedRowId);
      const data = snapshot.val() || {};
      const sortedBudgets = Object.keys(data).map((category) => ({
        category,
        budget: data[category],
      })).sort((a, b) => a.category.localeCompare(b.category));
      setSortedBudgets(sortedBudgets);
    });
  });
}, [sortedBudgets]);
```

Comment: Try adding console.log before rows creation. What data are there? Other thing - I think child_change doesn't return whole collection, but only this element data. Perhaps that's causing some issues?